# Localization of app doesn't change language of cocoapods used within app

Tags: ios, swift, localization, cocoapods

I am doing localization in my app. When I change the language it updates everywhere in my app except in pods that I have used. If I restart the app, pod's language is updated. Is there any way I can change the language of pods when I change the app's language.

Answer (score 0):

**You would need to swap the `mainBundle` of your application as soon as the user changes their language preferences inside the app.**

The idea is to have a custom Bundle and extension:

```
var bundleKey: UInt8 = 0

class AnyLanguageBundle: Bundle {

override func localizedString(forKey key: String,
                              value: String?,
                              table tableName: String?) -> String {

    guard let path = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &bundleKey) as? String,
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path) else {
        return super.localizedString(forKey: key, value: value, table: tableName)
    }

    return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: value, table: tableName)
  }
}

extension Bundle {

class func setLanguage(_ language: String) {

    defer {
        object_setClass(Bundle.main, AnyLanguageBundle.self)
    }

    objc_setAssociatedObject(Bundle.main, &bundleKey, Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj"), .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
  }
}
```

And when you would like to update your app language:

```
func updateAppLanguageToIT() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set("it", forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    // Update the language by swaping bundle
    Bundle.setLanguage("it")

    // Done to reintantiate the storyboards instantly
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
}
```

A few references on how to achieve this are available already in some posts/github pages like those two:

- https://github.com/maximbilan/Language-Manager-iOS
- http://www.codebales.com/how-programmatically-change-app-language-without-restarting-app

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same, swapping the mainBundle. Language of my app changes without restarting. Issue is with the pods, they are not updated unless I restart my app.